# Serial overflow in Arduino

Tags: arduino

When reading SMS using an Arduino program, the serial monitor shows only the senders (no date or time) and truncates the message. This is may be due to serial overflow, a common problem in Arduino.

**Code:**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <String.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 8);
void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(9600);               
  Serial.begin(9600);    

}


void loop()
{
 mySerial.print("AT+CMGR=1\r");
 delay(100);
 while(mySerial.available())
   Serial.write(mySerial.read());
   delay(1000);
}
```

**Output**

```
AT+CMGR=1

+CMGR: "REC READ","+XXXXX","A Silky Soni","1AT+CMGR=1

+CMGR: "REC READ","+XXXXX","A Silky Soni","1AT+CMGR=1

+CMGR: "REC READ","+XXXXX","A Silky Soni","1AT+CMGR=1
```

Comment: What are you reading SMS from?

Comment: your while() loop in the loop() function lacks curly braces; you should use those to make sure that the delay(1000) call gets included in that loop.

Comment: Sir, im reading SMS from a GSM sheild(SIM 900)

Answer (score 1):

You might need to adjust the baud rate in your code to match the GSM shield.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the baud rate, because the string is legible so all the bits are in the correct position, however the string is truncated.

This happen because the output buffer in `mySerial` take more time to be filled by the GSM shield than the time to be depleted by the `mySerial.read()` instruction. That's it: when `mySerial.available()` is checked and the GSM shield don't have time to put anything in the output buffer, the result is the fail of the `while` loop. There are some ways to face that problem:

**Put a `delay()` with specific time inside the `while`:**

```
void loop()
{
         mySerial.print("AT+CMGR=1\r");
         delay(100);
         while(mySerial.available()){
           Serial.write(mySerial.read());
           delay(100);  //fix the time according to how fast the GSM shield
                        //wrote the data in the serial port. 
         }
         delay(1000);
}
```

**Or use a timeout:**

```
unsigned long init_time, timeout=500;//choose the correct timeout value  
void loop()
{
 mySerial.print("AT+CMGR=1\r");
 //delay(100); //this delay can be omitted
 init_time=millis();
 do{
   while(mySerial.available()){
     Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     init_time=millis();
   }  
 }while(millis()-init_time < timeout);
 delay(1000);
}
```

The `millis()-init_time` give the time elapsed since the last time the `mySerial.available()` return true or before the check if never was available. **The code will still checking for availability until reach the timeout limit.**

I suggest the last approach. Happy coding!